# Laravel Blade Code Coverage

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel project which uses code coverage metrics as part of the release process. I've had a few instances where releases have included bugs despite having 100% code coverage. This is because there have been bugs inside blade template files. E.g. undefined variables in if statements... These kind of bugs would be detected if code coverage included blade files.

Is there a way to enable code coverage of Laravel Blade template files?

Comment: Having 100% code coverage doesn't necessarily mean you have correct tests written. You should provide an example of the code and test that showcases the problem.

Comment: You could add some controller tests where you check the response